# Window Vs GroupBy Performance in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am newbie to spark and I have observed that there are some cases that a window function approach and groupBy approach are alternatives for each other.Here,I want to understand from performance perspective which one is better and why?Both approaches will cause re-shuffling of data, but under which scenarios one will be effective over the other?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, `groupBy` is more performant because it uses partial aggregaton. So using `groupBy`, not all records are shuffled but only the partial aggregators (for example for `avg`, that would be sum and count).

On the other hand, window-function will always shuffle your records and aggregation is done afterward and should therefore be slower.

But in reality there is not the choice `groupBy` vs window-functions since in most cases you will need to combine `groupBy` results with a join with the original data (which can be expensive unless you can use broadcast join), and more often you cannot achieve the logic with `groupBy` (running sum/average, lead/lag etc).

But unfortunately, there is very little (official) literature about topics like that...

Comment: I read that if there is a join followed by groupBy then spark tries to shuffle the data in a optimal way.
https://umbertogriffo.gitbooks.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/content/avoiding_shuffle_less_stage,_more_fast.html
I mean that it will shuffle the data in such a way that minimum shuffling is done between grouby and join operations ,but there is no much reading on this.

Comment: @Hitesh but this documentation is related to RDD, maybe different for Dataset/Dataframe